# How to get weather alerts using RSS in Conky?

Tags: rss, conky

Quick question about how to get weather alerts with conky.

I'm using the following bit of code:

```
${execpi 3600 ~/.conky/scripts/conky-rss.sh "http://www.weather.gov/alerts/wwarssget.php?zone=MDZ006"|sed '1,3d'|fold -sw 62}
```

This (correctly) display a message to the effect "There are no weather alerts for ...." when there are no weather alerts. However, when there is an alert, it simply displays a message like "Short-term forecast for ..." with no further information.

Any suggestions?

How are other people getting weather alert info in their conkys?

Answer (score 1):

Can this link be of help? https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=37381